# How can I specify the hour at which my daily schedule of the DejaVu backup tool should run?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, schedule

How can I specify the hour at which my daily schedule of the DejaVu backup tool should run?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the question is about deja-dup, you can't.

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191